# Removing space after a graphic

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I have the following code and inputted a graphic at some point. When I compile the code, there is a huge white space after the graphic and before the text after the graphic. How do I reduce this white space?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[right=3cm, left=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{..}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{..}
\end{center}
text..
```

Comment: When you say 'after' the graphic, do you mean to the left/right or top/bottom?

Comment: I mean at the bottom of the graphic.

Comment: The space is not coming from the graphics but by your use of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. If you replace this with {\centering \includegraphics{...}} you should get less space around your image.

Comment: @ArTourter I tried that but now the image is somehow right aligned and there is still a huge gap EDIT: I fixed the right alignment and it it now centered but by using \centering instead there is still this huge gap?.

Comment: @CAF there isn't for me. Are you sure the white space is not part of the graphic you are including? can you add the actual MWE that create the error?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the white space is part of the graphic. It is fixed now.

Comment: @CAF `%` can be your friend for space manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, there is no white space. Your example would then become

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[right=3cm, left=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{..}

\begin{document}
{\centering 
\includegraphics{..}
}

text..
```

Note the curly braces to enclose the `\centering` to make sure it does not affect the rest of the document.

Comment: I have tried this but there is still the white space?